# Remove the last part of string separated with dot in Python

Tags: python, regex

How is it possible to convert in elegant way strings like:

```
'test.test1.test2'
'test.test3.test4'
```

into strings like these:

```
'test.test1'
'test.test3'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No need for regular expressions here.

Use [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
output = inputstr.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
```

or [`str.rpartition()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
output = inputstr.rpartition('.')[0]
```

`str.rpartition()` is the faster of the two but you need Python 2.5 or newer for it.

Demo:

```
>>> 'test.test1.test2'.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
'test.test1'
>>> 'test.test1.test2'.rpartition('.')[0]
'test.test1'
>>> 'test.test3.test4'.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
'test.test3'
>>> 'test.test3.test4'.rpartition('.')[0]
'test.test3'
```

And a time comparison against a million runs:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("s.rsplit('.', 1)[0]", "s = 'test.test1.test2'")
0.5848979949951172
>>> timeit("s.rpartition('.')[0]", "s = 'test.test1.test2'")
0.27417516708374023
```

where you can run 2 million `str.rpartition()` calls for the price of 1 million `str.rsplit()`'s.

Comment: It works very well in Python 3.9 for getting the parent of a file path using '/' instead of '.'

Comment: @SteffX: you want to use `os.path.split()` for that task, which can deal with OS-specific details and edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use rsplit to split from the end, limit to 1 split:

```
your_string.rsplit('.', 1)
```

Comment: newString = oldString.rsplit('.', 1)[0] - works good! Thanks a lot for the reply